# Data not saving while using $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a simple app and using `$resource` for the first time. I am trying to save data to a JSON object located in different folder. But I receive the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Following is my code:

**NewEvent.html**

```
<form name="editEventForm">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="eventName">Event Name:</label>
        <input id="eventName" type="text" required placeholder="Name of your event..." ng-model="event.name"> </br></br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="editEventForm.$invalid"  ng-click="saveEvent(event, editEventForm)">Save</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

**EditEventController.js**

```
eventsApp.controller('EditEventController', 
    function EditEventController($scope, eventData){

    $scope.saveEvent = function(event, editEventForm){
        if(editEventForm.$valid){
            eventData.save(event);
            console.log("Succeed");
            //window.alert('Event ' + {{event.name}} + ' is created.');
        }
    }

    $scope.cancelEdit = function(){
         window.location = 'EventDetails.html'; 
    }

});
```

**EventData.js**

```
eventsApp.factory('eventData', function($resource, $q){
    var resource = $resource('data/event/:id', {id: '@id'});
    return {
        getEvent: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();       
            resource.get({id:"1.json"},
                function(event) {
                    deferred.resolve(event);
                },
                function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                }
            );

            return deferred.promise; 
        },
        save: function(event) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(); 
            event.id = 999;
            resource.save(event,
                function(response) {deferred.resolve(response);},
                function(response) {deferred.reject(response);}
                );
            return deferred.promise; 
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This seems to be coming from your server. Can you paste a relevant snippet of code from your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can't post data to a static resource file such as `.json` extension

You must use a programming language on server to manipulate that file.

Request should go to a server side script endpoint